# AngularFire2 v5 not binding the $key property

Tags: typescript, firebase, angularfire

I am retrieving a list of users using angular fire like this:

`this.db.list<IUser>("usersinteam/04f27419-f466-4c5e-9816-fbf120713c4e").valueChanges<IUser>().subscribe( 
       res => console.log (res), 
       error => console.log (error), 
       () => console.log ("complete") );`

where the IUser interface in typescript looks like this:

`export interface IUser{
    $key: string,
    name: string,
    moto: string
}`

And the firebase json structure looks like this:
`{
  "04f27419-f466-4c5e-9816-fbf120713c4e" : {
    "2b395659-26f4-4c5c-a1b2-fd492d51ff5d" : {
      "moto" : "Nah!",
      "name" : "Maria"
    },
    "6b5c19b0-f176-4af1-ab19-ae7ec4c06a5a" : {
      "moto" : "Yeah!",
      "name" : "David"
    },
    "ee067245-f085-4c33-acaa-a16deb945cee" : {
      "moto" : "wrecking ball",
      "name" : "Ian"
    }
  }
}`

I am getting a list of IUser objects with the name and moto properties populated correctly. But the $key property is undefined. I was expecting to see the $key property set to the key for each user. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

They did away with the $key approach in version 5. Here are more details

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md